# Rails 3 uninitialized constant error, has_many and belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many, belongs-to, uninitialized-constant

I have created a simple has_many and belongs_to relationship between two activerecords and when i try to create uninitialized constant Tool::Version,

tool.rb:

```
class Tool < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  validates_presence_of :name
  has_many :versions
end
```

versions.rb

```
class Versions < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tool
  attr_accessible :tool_version
end
```

abc.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for([@tool, @tool.versions.build]) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :version %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :version %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>     
    </div>

<% end %>
```

on submit I get the error. what am i doing wrong here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text_field should be tool_version and not version

Answer (score 0):

You should change the class name

The class name should be `Version`, not `Versions`

```
class Versions < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tool
  attr_accessible :tool_version
end
```